# Horizontal scrolling flex list with full width items

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox

I try to write a horizontal scrollable list where each elements have the full width.

In the following example the blue area should have the same size as the area with the gray boxes.

```css
.scroller {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 74px;
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 64px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
}

.blue {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But if I scroll to the right, the blue element stops at 100% width of the parent. The strange is that the red background color of all items stops at 100% too.

I tried it with nearly every combination of width, min-width, fit-content, inline-flex and so on.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Edit:
In production there will be more than two items, and all items have to be scrolled together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra wrapper that you make `inline-block` and use width for the flex item

```css
.scroller {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.scroller>div {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 74px;
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 64px;
  width:64px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
}

.blue {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there what you need?

```css
.scroller {
 width: max-content;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 74px;
}

.block {
  min-width: 64px;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
}

.blue {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put overflow: auto or scroll to a parent of an overflowing child items

```css
.scroller {
  max-width: 600px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  height: 74px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto
}

.block {
  flex: 0 0 64px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin: 5px;
}

.blue {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This not the function i want. All items have to scroll together, because there could be much more than two items, and i do not want to have a scrollbar per item